# How to deep copy elasticsearch QueryBuilder?

Tags: elasticsearch, deep-copy

I have a use case where I have a `boolQueryBuilder` which is common across different type of queries.

Now for different queries, I need to add a different `must()` to the `boolQueryBuilder`.

Basically, say I have a common `boolQueryBuilder` which is built to filter books with certain tags. Now among these when I get a request to select specific type1/type2 I have to do

`boolQueryBuilder.must(type1)` for request1
`boolQueryBuilder.must(type2)` for request2 (which shouldnt have type1)

I tried `deepcopy`, `serialize` and `deserialize` but they are very very slow takes ~3 seconds

I need *type1* along with the tags in *request1*, and *type2* along with tags in *request2*.

What is the best way to make use of the common builder I have instead of re-building the common queries again and again?

Comment: Have you tried  json serialization/deserialization ? If that is slow, then instead of serialization/deserialization , why dont you have a factory/ helper which gives back an new instance of boolQueryBuilder ? Something along the lines of getCommonFilter() which creates a new queryBuilder object and returns it. I am assuming the common boolQueryBuilder doesnt change at all. At all costs, avoid making it static

Comment: @Ram were u able to figure it out?

Comment: I wrote a custom builder which given a SearchSourceBuilder extracts the list<QueryBuilder> mustQueries; List<QueryBuilder> shouldQueries; and wrote a custom builder on top of it which will add and return new searchSourceBuilder() build from these lists.  

Basically parsing is done only once, and then this factory class will take care to return new builders every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient solution but the quickest to implement and doesn't hurt performance. For a really efficient implementation you may need to write a custom builder that creates your copy.
I created a `List<QueryBuilder>` and added my `TermQueryBuilder` and `TermsQueryBuilder` to it. Creating a `List` of `QueryBuilder` will support
adding most queries. 
Since I had to reuse it each time for a new copy of a `BoolQueryBuilder`, I just initialized it and iterated over the list to add the queries.

```
List<QueryBuilder> queryBuilderList = new ArrayList<>();
queryBuilderList.add(QueryBuilders.termQuery(key, value));
queryBuilderList.add(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(key, value));

// Somewhere later
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (int i = 0; i < queryBuilderList.size(); i++) {
   boolQueryBuilder.must(queryBuilderList.get(i));
}
```